# Click on textarea show submit button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to click on textarea after click show submit button. My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tuudvj9m/

```
<div class="panel">
    <form action="" mathod="post" class="panel-body panel-300">
        <textarea class="form-control expandable" type="text" id="myIn" placeholder="Write a Review" rows="2"></textarea><br />
        <input type="button" class="btn btnshow" value="Save" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" class="btn btnshow" value="Cancle" />
    </form>      
</div>
```

```css
.panel textarea.expandable {
    height:40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
textarea.expandable:hover, 
textarea.expandable:focus {
    height: calc(100% - 90px);      
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.panel-300:hover, 
.panel-300 {
    height: 200px;    
} 
textarea.expandable + textarea.expandable:hover, 
textarea.expandable + textarea.expandable:focus {
    height: calc(100% - 90px)   
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? unclear.

Comment: Do you want to show submit button on click of textarea?

Comment: click on text area box after show me submit or cancel button

Comment: Yes @Farhan I want to Click on Textarea then show button .

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/tuudvj9m/2/).

Comment: [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tuudvj9m/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of textarea button will be visible, and onclick of cancel buttons will be invisible

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myIn").on('click', function() {
    $("#saveBtn").show();
    $("#cancelBtn").show();
  });

  $("#cancelBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#saveBtn").hide();
    $("#cancelBtn").hide();
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
  <form action="" mathod="post" class="panel-body panel-300">
    <textarea class="form-control expandable" type="text" id="myIn" placeholder="Write a Review" rows="2"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" class="btn btnshow" id="saveBtn" value="Save" style='display:none;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="cancelBtn" class="btn btnshow" value="Cancle" style='display:none;' />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnshow').hide();

  $('#myIn').focusin(function() { $('.btnshow').show() }
});
```

That will only handle what you asked for you would need to add additional validation if the textarea loses focus and is blank to re-hide the buttons.

Comment: brackets are missing please update your code, also replace "dot" with comma after $(document), rest code is working good

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of using javascript...
HTML Code

```
<form action="" mathod="post" class="panel-body panel-300">
 <textarea class="form-control expandable" type="text" id="txtarea" placeholder="Write a Review" rows="2"></textarea><br />
                                                                         <input type="button" class="btn btnshow" value="Save" id="btnsave" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn btnshow" value="Cancle" />
 </form>
```

JS Code

```
window.onload = function() {
     var tt = document.getElementById('txtarea');
var btnsave = document.getElementById('btnsave');
tt.onclick = function(){btnsave.style.display='block';}


};
```